# Module xxx/xxx is not connected on Raspberry Pi

Tags: azure-iot-edge

All,
  I am porting some modules from Ubuntu to Raspbain and using a Python module, I am getting the error:

> 2018-10-03 17:52:11.964 +00:00 [WRN] - Module pi/sample is not
>   connected 2018-10-03 17:52:39.530 +00:00 [WRN] - TLS handshake
>   failed., System.IO.IOException: Channel is closed, 555eae73

I am using the sample python module from VS Code.  The exact same 'main.py' work on ubuntu.

Repro on Ubuntu:
1. Follow: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/quickstart-linux.
2. in VS Code create a new sample module python.  Push that to your docker repository
3. In portal.azure.com push both modules to your iot edge host with the following route:

```
  "routes": {
    "a": "FROM /messages/modules/tempSensor/outputs/* INTO BrokeredEndpoint(\"/modules/sample/inputs/input1\")",
    "b": "FROM /messages/modules/sample/outputs/output1 INTO $upstream"
  },
```

4. after a few minutes running docker logs edgeHub you will see:

018-10-03 17:51:53.270 +00:00 [INF] - Successfully generated identity for clientId ubuntu1/sample and username ksayeaz3166.azure-devices.net/ubuntu1/sample/?api-version=2017-11-08-preview&DeviceClientType=iothubclient%2f1.2.5%20(native%3b%20Linux%3b%20x86_64)
2018-10-03 17:51:53.275 +00:00 [INF] - ClientAuthenticated, ubuntu1/sample, 2ae77b92
2018-10-03 17:51:53.345 +00:00 [INF] - New device connection for device ubuntu1/sample

Repro on Pi:
1. Follow: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/quickstart-linux.
2. in VS Code create a new sample module python.  Push that to your docker repository
3. In portal.azure.com push both modules to your iot edge host with the following route:

```
  "routes": {
    "a": "FROM /messages/modules/tempSensor/outputs/* INTO BrokeredEndpoint(\"/modules/sample/inputs/input1\")",
    "b": "FROM /messages/modules/sample/outputs/output1 INTO $upstream"
  },
```

4. after a few minutes running docker logs edgeHub you will see:

> 2018-10-03 17:52:11.964 +00:00 [WRN] - Module pi/sample is not
>   connected 2018-10-03 17:52:39.530 +00:00 [WRN] - TLS handshake
>   failed., System.IO.IOException: Channel is closed, 555eae73 2018-10-03
>   17:53:11.966 +00:00 [WRN] - Module pi/sample is not connected
>   2018-10-03 17:54:03.357 +00:00 [INF] - Reauthenticating connected
>   clients 2018-10-03 17:54:12.079 +00:00 [WRN] - Module pi/sample is not
>   connected

I have mode no changes to the python module sample code.

PI info:
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# uname -a
Linux raspberrypi 4.14.70-v7+ #1144 SMP Tue Sep 18 17:34:46 BST 2018 armv7l GNU/Linux

root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# docker version
Client:
 Version:      18.06.0-dev
 API version:  1.37
 Go version:   go1.10.2
 Git commit:   daf021fe
 Built:        Wed Jun 27 00:53:52 2018
 OS/Arch:      linux/arm
 Experimental: false
 Orchestrator: swarm

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:      dev
  API version:  1.37 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:   go1.10.2
  Git commit:   9aac187
  Built:        Tue Jun 26 23:27:27 2018
  OS/Arch:      linux/arm
  Experimental: false

Ubuntu Info:

ksaye@ksaye-700T:~/iotedge$ uname -a
Linux ksaye-700T 4.13.0-41-generic #46~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 3 10:06:43 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

ksaye@ksaye-700T:~/iotedge$ docker version
Client:
 Version:       17.12.0-ce
 API version:   1.35
 Go version:    go1.9.2
 Git commit:    c97c6d6
 Built: Wed Dec 27 20:11:19 2017
 OS/Arch:       linux/amd64

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:      17.12.0-ce
  API version:  1.35 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:   go1.9.2
  Git commit:   c97c6d6
  Built:        Wed Dec 27 20:09:53 2017
  OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
  Experimental: false
ksaye@ksaye-700T:~/iotedge$

Answer (score 1):

Adding the OptimizedForPerformance setting discussed here resolve it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/troubleshoot#stability-issues-on-resource-constrained-devices